# Need to retrieve current element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to get current element node but im getting only the value of element. please help me..

```
<root><LIST>
                     <ROLE>s1</ROLE>
                    <STATUS>yes</STATUS>
                </LIST>
                <LIST>
                    <ROLE>s1</ROLE>
                    <STATUS>yes</STATUS>
                </LIST>
                 <LIST>
                    <ROLE>Member</ROLE>
                    <STATUS>no</STATUS>
                </LIST>
                 <LIST>
                    <ROLE>Member</ROLE>
                    <STATUS>no</STATUS>
                </LIST>
                 <LIST>
                    <ROLE>Member</ROLE>
                    <STATUS>yes</STATUS>
                </LIST>
                </root>
```

and i tried like

```
                <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/"><html>
    <h2>
<xsl:element name="test">
    <xsl:for-each select="/root/LIST[STATUS='yes']">
<xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
</h2></html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But im getting only the values of the element. i need to retrieve current element with value. does anyone have idea

Comment: your xslt is not valid, if i remove </xsl:if> the output is as expected, including tags.. what is your desired output?

Comment: sorry i was posted wrong code. now i updated code. still i am getting the values alone not elements.

Comment: how does [this](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/YTqkzr) differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:element name="test">     
>   <xsl:for-each select="/root/LIST[STATUS='yes']"> 
>     <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
>   </xsl:for-each>       
> </xsl:element>
> ```

This is a rather weird way of saying:

```
<test>
 <xsl:copy-of select="/root/LIST[STATUS='yes']"/>
</test>
```

**So, the complete transformation can be just this:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <h2>
                <test>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="/root/LIST[STATUS='yes']"/>
                </test>
            </h2>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <LIST>
        <ROLE>s1</ROLE>
        <STATUS>yes</STATUS>
    </LIST>
    <LIST>
        <ROLE>s1</ROLE>
        <STATUS>yes</STATUS>
    </LIST>
    <LIST>
        <ROLE>Member</ROLE>
        <STATUS>no</STATUS>
    </LIST>
    <LIST>
        <ROLE>Member</ROLE>
        <STATUS>no</STATUS>
    </LIST>
    <LIST>
        <ROLE>Member</ROLE>
        <STATUS>yes</STATUS>
    </LIST>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<html>
   <h2>
      <test>
         <LIST>
            <ROLE>s1</ROLE>
            <STATUS>yes</STATUS>
         </LIST>
         <LIST>
            <ROLE>s1</ROLE>
            <STATUS>yes</STATUS>
         </LIST>
         <LIST>
            <ROLE>Member</ROLE>
            <STATUS>yes</STATUS>
         </LIST>
      </test>
   </h2>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use...

```
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
```

and delete the unmatched xsl:if like so...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
    <h2>
      <xsl:element name="test">
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/LIST[STATUS='yes']">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>
    </h2>
   </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result will be this...

```
<html>
  <h2><test><LIST>
                     <ROLE>s1</ROLE>
                    <STATUS>yes</STATUS>
                </LIST><LIST>
                    <ROLE>s1</ROLE>
                    <STATUS>yes</STATUS>
                </LIST><LIST>
                    <ROLE>Member</ROLE>
                    <STATUS>yes</STATUS>
                </LIST>
    </test>
   </h2>
</html>
```